# Quanteda: How to look up patterns of two or more words in a phrase, when there can be any number of words in between?

Tags: r, dictionary, glob, quanteda

I want to match some patterns in a text in R using the package `{quanteda}` and the `tokens_lookup()` function with the default `valuetype="glob"`. The pattern would be the occurrence of one word in connection with a second word located anywhere in the same phrase.

```
library(quanteda)

text <- c(d1 = "apples word word word oranges", 
          d2 = "apples oranges", 
          d3 = "oranges and apples")

dict <- dictionary(list(fruits = c("apple* orange*")))

tokens(text) %>% 
  tokens_lookup(dict, valuetype = "glob") %>% 
  dfm()
```

Applying this dictionary to the tokenized text from above would yield a result of 0-1-0, while I would expect 1-1-0.

So my question would be, what's with blank spaces in glob pattern matching and shouldn't asterisks match everything including blank spaces? More generally, how can I match d1, d2, and potentially d3 with one and the same pattern?

**EDIT:**

In regex pattern matching this wouldn't be much of an issue. Example:

```
text <- c(d1 = "apples word word word oranges", 
          d2 = "apples oranges")

dict <- dictionary(list(fruits = c("apples.*oranges")))

tokens(text, what="sentence") %>%
  tokens_lookup(dict, valuetype = "regex") %>%
  dfm()
```

Comment: using `dictionary(list(fruits = c("apple*",  "orange*")))` will result in 2-2-2, instead of 0-1-0

Comment: Oh right, but I would like to go for ngrams where you specify a combination of words. Imagine something like "I hate apples", "Apples are something I hate", "I like apples" and based on that you want to filter for statements against apples.

Comment: What result do you want to see? Do you expect a match for d3? (because the order differs)

Comment: No, actually I just expected a match for the first two and then I reckoned I could just switch the order for instances in which oranges are prior.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for answering my questions, by the way! Quanteda is a really cool package!

Answer (score 1):

`tokens()` segments on whitespace, and `tokens_lookup()` finds patterns in tokens - or in sequences of tokens if the pattern contains whitespace in your dictionary value.  To use glob matching to get any token between two more specific patterns, you can specify a `*` as that part of the pattern.  (Technically, patterns with whitespace are parsed into sequences called in quanteda-speak "phrases".  See `?phrase`.)

So to slightly modify your example:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.0.1

text <- c(
  d1 = "apples word word oranges",
  d2 = "apples and oranges",
  d3 = "oranges and apples"
)

dict <- dictionary(list(fruits = c(
  "apple* * orange*",
  "apple* * * orange*"
)))

tokens(text) %>%
  tokens_lookup(dict, valuetype = "glob", exclusive = FALSE)
## Tokens consisting of 3 documents.
## d1 :
## [1] "FRUITS"
## 
## d2 :
## [1] "FRUITS"
## 
## d3 :
## [1] "oranges" "and"     "apples"
```

Here, we get the pattern of `apple*` followed by one of any token or two of any token, followed by `orange*`.

This will *not* pick up the "orange" followed by "apple" however since that's the reverse sequences, and will not pick up just "apple orange" since there is not some token between them.  (But you could add that case by adding a third value to your `fruits` key as just `"apple* orange*".)

Comment: Again, thank you for this, it's really helpful. Though, what if I wanted to match a phrase that can be of _any length_ and that contains the two words (be it a bigram or just a co-occurence of two words in a phrase in a particular order)? In regex pattern matching this would not be a problem (see my edit, above).

Comment: That won't span tokens though, so would not work the way we have implemented the parse tokens + parse pattern then match tokens sequences to phrases approach. You'd have to implement the matching using logical regex matches on the raw text.

Comment: Hm, are you sure it wouldn't work? In the example above it seems to work just fine at least for regex matching (see "EDIT"). `what="sentence"` should essentially preserve the sentence structure, no?